# Websphere JDBC-adapter fails to call an oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, websphere, adapter

I've posted to the mqseries forum too, but haven't got any answers yet.
I have problems using a Websphere adapter for JDBC in order to call an Oracle stored procedure. The procedure looks like this:

```
create or replace
procedure sp_myproc(par_out out SYS_REFCURSOR) 
as 
begin 
    open par_out  for select * from my_table; 
end;
```

I have generated the BO definition using ODA. I have also read this:http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v7r0mx/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.wsadapters.jca.jdbc.doc%2Fdoc%2Fcjdb_ov_storedproc_bo.html

My question is how to specify the ASI for the RetrieveSP correctly? 
If I use: `SPN=sp_myproc;RS=true;OP=RS` I get the following error: "ResultSet as output parameter for Stored Procedure not supported for database Oracle and JDBC Driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver".

Comment: The error message says it isn't supported, so I think you simply can't do this.

Comment: the help says I can do it with Oracle, and they mention the same driver that i use (ojdbc14.jar)

Comment: That the Driver can do it, does not mean that this adapter supports it with Oracle.